# Terraform | default_node_pool - Dot must be followed by attribute name

Tags: azure, automation, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm currently working on a terraform file azure.tf and it seems that at the time that I'm running the following command:

```
terraform init
```

This is my output:

```
│ Error: Attribute name required
│
│   on azure.tf line 168, in resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s_cluster":
│  168:       "default_node_pool.0.node_count"
│
│ Dot must be followed by attribute name.
```

This is the tag and the code that I'm using for the lifecycle inside of azure.tf:

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "default_node_pool.0.node_count"
    ]
  }
```

What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can we see some Terraform code? Especially `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster` block.

Comment: I added what I have in the lifecycle which is the line that it doesn't like

Comment: That name does appear incorrect. Could you add `default_node_pool` to the question?

Comment: Could you try just `default_node_pool.node_count`?

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

***You don't have to use `default_node_pool.0.node_count` in double quotes i.e. `" "`***.

So instead of using the below ,

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "default_node_pool.0.node_count"
    ]
  }
```

You have to use ,

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      default_node_pool.0.node_count
    ]
  }
```

---

I tested the same using ***your lifecycle block*** which gave me the same error on doing `terraform init`.

[image]

***Using the solution mentioned above in the below resource block for `kubernetes` resolved the issue :***

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features{}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
  name                = "example-aks1"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  dns_prefix          = "exampleaks1"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v2"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
        default_node_pool.0.node_count
        ]
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

***After upgrading the node count from portal , I did a Terraform apply again like below:***

[image]

[image]